# Rails: how to save statistics based on some conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm developing a Rails application and I need to save and show some statistics based on the following conditions:

- For the current month, display all entries in the database
- For the last 8 months, display a cumulative of each month
- For the rest, show a cumulative of all values

The thing is that I don't want to save all the data in my database and than apply the condition when showing. Is there a way of keeping my database structured in a way that it also covers the conditions (for example, when the current month changes, apply all the conditions and update the database)?